# Is the module of Kähler differentials a coend?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, kahler-differentials

Let $\phi\colon R\to S$ be a ring map. The module of Kähler differentials $\Omega_{S/R}$ of $\phi$ [can be constructed](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM) as the following coequaliser:
$$\left(\bigoplus_{(a, b)\in S^2} S[(a, b)]\right) \oplus\left( \bigoplus_{(f, g)\in S^2} S[(f, g)]\right)\oplus\left(  \bigoplus_{r\in R} S[r] \right)\underset{0}{\rightrightarrows}\bigoplus_{a\in S} S[a],$$
where the above map is defined by
$$
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)] &\mapsto [a+b]-[a]-[b],\\
[(f,g)] &\mapsto [fg] -f[g]-g[f],\\
[r]     &\mapsto [\phi(r)].
\end{align*}
$$
This looks strikingly similar to the colimit formula for computing enriched co/ends, which given a $\mathsf{Mod}_R$-functor $P\colon\mathcal{C}^\mathsf{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathsf{Mod}_R$, takes the form
$$
\int^{M\in\mathsf{Mod}_R}P(M,M)=\mathrm{Coeq}\left(\bigoplus_{\phi\colon M\to N\in\mathsf{Mod}_R}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Mod}_R}(M,N)\otimes_RP(N,M)\rightrightarrows\bigoplus_{M\in\mathsf{Mod}_R}P(M,M)\right).$$

**Question.** Can we write $\Omega_{S/R}$ as a coend in a "nice"* way?

*That is, without directly using the definition of $\Omega_{S/R}$ (e.g. using the functor $\mathrm{Der}_R(S,-)$ to build the desired coend would certainly be "nice").

---

Here's a failed short attempt, for what it's worth. Using the Density Theorem and the isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Mod}_R}(R,M)\cong M$, one can write
$$\Omega_{S/R}\cong\int^{M\in\mathsf{Mod}_R}(-)\otimes_R\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Mod}_R}(-,\Omega_{S/R}),$$
but it now seems difficult to give a "nice" description of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Mod}_R}(-,\Omega_{S/R})$.